# if statement inside Where on LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

assume I have customer table with ( name column and number column)
user can do query to display the one name's number
or display all number if there is no restrict ;

this example

```
    void DisplayNumbersOfName(string name)
     {
        using (dataclassDataContext db = new dataclassDataContext())
           {
               if(name=="")
               var Names = from ta in db.table_accounts

                           select ( ta );
                else
                Names = from ta in db.table_accounts
                           where ta.name = name
                           select ( ta );

        }
     }
```

I don't want use this way because the method is

more complex , I want only change on 'where ' WHERE with IF

Answer (score 5):

You should use the fact that LINQ queries *compose* nicely - and that you don't need to use the query expression syntax. So:

```
// Fixing naming conventions as I go, to make the code more idiomatic...
using (DataClassDataContext db = new DataClassDataContext())
{
    IQueryable<YourDataType> query = db.TableAccounts;
    if (name != "")
    {
        query = query.Where(ta => ta.Name == name);
    }
    // Use query here...
}
```

walther's solution is another viable alternative, but it does mean evaluating the "do we really want this as part of the query" in the database - you'll end up with SQL which is somewhat harder to understand. Personally I prefer to be explicit about whether you want a particular filter to be part of the query.

Comment: @user1447244: What's unclear about it? It creates a query (and that *doesn't* execute anything until you start using it) and then creates a new query based on the existing one, if and only if you need filtering.

Answer (score 5):

```
 void DisplayNumbersOfName(string name)
 {
    using (dataclassDataContext db = new dataclassDataContext())
    {
        var Names = from ta in db.table_accounts
                    where (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || ta.name == name)
                    select ( ta );

    }
 }
```

Haven't checked it to be honest, but it should work.

Comment: That should work, but it won't give the OP what they're looking for.  It will give the OP all the records where the name column equals a provided value *or* it's an empty string.   OP's code is looking for a record equal to name *or* all the records.

Comment: @Tim: It *will* work, because if name is `""`, it will match all records.

Comment: @JonSkeet - That seems like strange behavior and rather counter-intuitive.  Is there a reason behind that behavior?

Comment: @Tim: Why is it counter-intuitive? If name is "", the conditional always holds. Imagine that you first fetched all records, then processed them one by one, filtering with an `if` statement - if name was "", it would *always* go into the body of the `if`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Tim, what do you find strange about it? If the `name` is empty, it doesn't evaluate the second condition at all, so it matches every row. If it isn't empty, it evaluates only the second condition as true, so it's the same as `WHERE ta.name == name`. A different thing would be to say `WHERE (ta.Name == "" || ta.Name == name)`. Then you'd be right.

Comment: sory I have checked it , but NOT WORK, beacuse if names is"" that don't mean all result

Comment: @user1447244, you've actually tried it or just evaluated it in your head? Cause if there isn't a typo, it works, as Jon Skeet already said as well. It returns all results, because then the whole `where` clause is true. Same way it would be as if it looked like `where 1=1`...

Comment: @JonSkeet - Doh!  That's what I get for not reading closely enough.  When I looked at the code I thought it was checking for the column "name" to be empty - not simply the variable.  Excuse me while I go clean the egg off my face :)

Comment: @user1447244, you've actually tried it or just evaluated it in your head?
 NO I tried it , and this is my Problem

Comment: @user1447244, check the revised version. I've added a check for null value as well, cause you don't specify what exactly are you passing in. However, if you pass a different value than `null` or `empty`, you need to check for that value instead! The concept itself is good, you just need to adapt it to your needs. I've already used this approach multiple times in my projects, so I'm sure it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
db.table_accounts.Where(p=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)||p.name = name);
```